# PHP generated form does not submit AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have a select with ROWID in the value and the name in the value,

```
<select name="opcoes"  onchange="showInfo(this.value)">
<option value=''>Select</option>
<option value=6>A</option>
<option value=2>F</option>
<option value=5>L</option>
<option value=1>M</option>
</select>
```

when you select one i have this ajax code to create a form with php,

```
    function showInfo(str)
{


if (str=="")
  {

  document.getElementById("fields").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("fields").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","php/vendors/getRow.php?id="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Next if the selected value isnt "" it goes to the php,

...conection to the database...

```
echo "<form action='/php/vendors/edit.php' onSubmit=\"return confirm('Deseja editar?')\" method='post' >"; 
echo "<td><input type='text' name='editname'   value='".utf8_encode($linha[vendor_name])."'    ></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='editemail'    value='".utf8_encode($linha[vendor_email])."'    ></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='editwebsite'    value='".utf8_encode($linha[vendor_website])."'  ></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='editphone'    value='".utf8_encode($linha[vendor_phone])."'    ></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='editfax'     value='".utf8_encode($linha[vendor_fax])."'     ></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='editadress'    value='".utf8_encode($linha[vendor_adress])."'   ></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='editincharge'   value='".utf8_encode($linha[vendor_incharge])."'  ></td>";
echo "<td class='btn'><input class='edit' type='submit' value=''></td>";
echo "</form>";
```

It displays every information correctly the ONLY problem is that it does not submit when i click the input submit button... any ideas why?

Comment: Is the function defined before or after the HTML elements? If before, you should wrap it inside a `window.onload` and assign the `onclick` from there

Comment: i link the script in the head of the html... i didnt understand what you meant... it is called after the page loads and the user selects an option

Comment: is the confirm dialog shown?

Comment: no :( nothing dont know why :D

Comment: Any errors in the console (F12)?

Comment: do you work with an image button? try to set a value to your submit input.

Comment: It doesn't work because `onSubmit=\"return confirm('Deseja editar?')\"` the function confirm doesn't exist?

Comment: confirm is a basic javascript function and should allways exist.

Comment: no errors in the console and yes confirm exists...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are generating invalid HTML.

A form can contain an entire table. A table cell can contain an entire row. A form cannot exist inside a table but around a set of cells in that table.

Your browser is error recovering by moving the form to *after the table* but *leaving the form controls behind*.

This means that the submit button isn't inside a form so it can't submit a form.

Comment: @André Alvarez As Quentin said, you have error in building form, first correct your html then try again

Comment: But this bit of code is inserted inside a <table> with a div if you check the ajax code "fields" in the html there is a <tr id="fields">

Comment: @AndréAlvarez — That's my point. `<tr><form><td></td></form></tr>` is invalid and will not work.

Comment: So it should be?

<form><tr><td></td></tr></form>

Comment: No! Read the answer! You have to put the form around the *entire table* or entirely *inside a single cell*.

Comment: hmmm but it does work if i put it before a tr... i loose the table formating though (div)

Answer (score 0):

If you load dynamically HTML forms in your document, they aren't registered in the DOM.
Try to get this work with jQuery delegates [jQuery Delegates](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: They are registered in the DOM, just not when the page is loaded … but since the event handlers are not bound at page load time, that doesn't matter.

Comment: i think quentin is right. But using jquery is allways a good idea because he is able to replace the ugly selfmade xmlhttprequest with jquerys $.ajax...

Comment: You can have neater XHR code without resorting to the overhead of jQuery.